# Available Lightning Controller Data Types

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, controller, lightning-web-components

Where can I find a list of the acceptable datatypes for the lightning controller component.set() for list values? I can see that `type: 'text'` and `type: 'date'` and `type: 'boolean'` work but `integer` and `decimal` do not take. Is there a list available online?

```
({
doInit: function (component , event, helper) {
    component.set('v.columns', [
        {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text', editable: true, typeAttributes: { required: false }},
        {label: 'Campaign Hierarchy Number', fieldName: 'Campaign_Hierarchy_Number__c', type: 'formattedNumber', editable: true, typeAttributes: { required: false }},             
        {label: 'Start Date', fieldName: 'StartDate', type: 'date', editable: true, typeAttributes: { required: false }, 
                                typeAttributes: {
                                year: 'numeric',
                                month: 'short',
                                day: 'numeric',
                                hour: '2-digit',
                                minute: '2-digit'
        }},
        {label: 'Owner Name', fieldName: 'Owner.Name', type: 'text', editable: true, typeAttributes: { required: false }},
        {label: 'Type', fieldName: 'Type', type: 'action', editable: true, typeAttributes: { required: true }},
        {label: 'Tier', fieldName: 'Tier__c', type: 'action', editable: true, typeAttributes: { required: true }},
        {label: 'Campaign Participant?', fieldName: 'CampaignHierarchyParticipant__c', type: 'boolean', editable: true, typeAttributes: { required: true }},
        {label: 'Number Of Leads', fieldName: 'NumberOfLeads', type: 'number', editable: true, typeAttributes: { required: true }},
        {label: 'Number Of Opportunities', fieldName: 'NumberOfOpportunities', type: 'number', editable: true, typeAttributes: { required: true }},
        {label: 'Max Not Answered Allowed', fieldName: 'Max_Not_Answered_Allowed__c', type: 'number', editable: true, typeAttributes: { required: true }},
    ]);
        helper.getCampaignHierarchyList(component, helper);      
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about `lightning:datatable`, then the full list of acceptable are 
 in [Datatable Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation) in **Formatting with Data Types** section.

The full list: action, boolean, button, button-icon, currency, date, date-local, email, location, number, percent, phone, text, url.

Comment: when I try to use the data types listed in the documentation, number and action do not seem to register. I have also tried: formattedNumber. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Olivia i am not seeing any `type:number` columns in your above code snippet? can you update your question

Comment: @sdandamud1 I updated the post with the entire function I am trying to build

Comment: I got it, I was missing that field in the query. Once I updated the query, "number" was working. Thanks!